# Design choice: Use NSFetchedResultsController and store derived properties or roll my own data source?

Tags: swift-language

I'm writing an iOS app in Swift that calculates a '1 rep maximum' weight using two inputs, `weightLifted` and `repetitions`. One of several formulas is used to perform the calculation with these two inputs to arrive at the answer which is the 1 rep max. I'm only storing the input values, not the 1 rep max value. I'm also storing the `weightUnit` (kg or lb) of the `weightLifted`.

```
extension LiftEvent {
    @NSManaged var date: Date
    @NSManaged var repetitions: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var uid: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var weightLifted: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var weightUnit: String
    @NSManaged var formula: Formula
    @NSManaged var lift: Lift
}
```

I chose this approach because the computational cost is negligible and it makes weight unit conversion simple.

However, I've now discovered an unfortunate side effect of using an `NSFetchedResultsController` and have another choice to make. Each calculation result can be saved as a LiftEvent (the `NSManagedObject` seen above) but I can't sort by the 1 rep max result if I'm using an `NSFetchResultsController` because it's a derived property that is only created at runtime. It appears my choices are:

1. persist the 1 rep max value as another property of the LiftEvent so it can be included as a sort descriptor in the fetch request used by the `NSFetchedResultsController`
2. keep my data model the way it is, dump the `NSFetchedResultsController`, and instead create an array to hold my fetch request results, allowing me to convert and sort as needed, then make it my data source.

Option 1 is probably easier, but I never like to use that as a reason to do something. Unfortunately, because of the limitations of working with the fetched results once fetched make this about the only option I can think of that would allow me to keep the `NSFetchedResultsController`

What other things should I consider when making this decision?

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745999/how-can-i-set-a-custom-attribute-of-an-nsmanagedobject-which-is-calculated-from

Comment: Thank you, Samuel. After a brief look at it, I think you might be right.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unless something has changed it doesn't look like a transient variable will solve my problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381794/using-time-based-transient-property-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller). I created a transient variable to return the calculated value and that worked just fine, but what I want to do is sort by that calculated value and it appears that it's just not possible if I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController and I'll need to make a choice from the options I've described. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I would probably go with option #1 (add a persistent property) *and* use key-value observation to update that property automatically if the value of weightLifted or repetitions changes.